# How is Derivative causing NMaximize::nnum the function value is not a number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

```
pauliX = PauliMatrix[1];
pauliY = PauliMatrix[2];
pauliZ = PauliMatrix[3];
spinRaise = pauliX + I pauliY;
spinLower = pauliX - I pauliY;
pauli0 = 1/2 (IdentityMatrix[2] - (pauliZ/(2 + 1)));
zero = {1, 0};
one = {0, 1};
excluded = 
 "ExcludedFunctions" /. ("DifferentiationOptions" /. 
    SystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"])
SetSystemOptions[
 "DifferentiationOptions" -> 
  "ExcludedFunctions" -> Union[excluded, {Conjugate}]]


(*state1={Cos[θ],Exp[i ϕ].Sin[θ]};
den1=KroneckerProduct[state1,state1];
state2={Sin[θ],-Exp[i ϕ].Cos[θ]};
den2=KroneckerProduct[state2,state2];*)

stateEvolved[exite_,state_, rValue_, tauValue_] := Module[{},
   
   rho11 = zero.state.zero;
   rho22 = one.state.one;
   rho12 = zero.state.one;
   rho21 = one.state.zero;
   currR = rValue;
   currTau = tauValue;
   (*xi=(Exp[-Abs[eigen2]time]-R.Exp[-dissipation.time])/1-R;
   xi2=(Exp[-Abs[eigen2]time]-2.R.Exp[-dissipation.time])/1-2.R;*)
   
   xi = (Exp[-currR*currTau] - currR*Exp[-currTau])/(1 - currR);
   xi2 = (Exp[-2*currR*currTau] - 2*currR*Exp[-currTau])/(1 - 2*currR);
   (*eigen2=-2.phenDissipation(exciteNum+(1/2));*)
   
   rhoT = 1/
      2 (IdentityMatrix[
        2] - (xi*(rho11 - rho22 + (1/((2*exciteNum) + 1))) - 
          1/((2*exciteNum) + 1))*
        pauliZ + (xi2/2)*(rho12*spinRaise + rho21*spinLower));
   Return[rhoT];
   
   ];

traceDistance[excite_densityState1_, densityState2_, rValue_, tauValue_] := 
  Module[{},
   
   evolvedState1 = stateEvolved[densityState1, rValue, tauValue];
   evolvedState2 = stateEvolved[densityState2, rValue, tauValue];
   stateDifference = evolvedState1 - evolvedState2;
   trd = 1/
      2 (Tr[Sqrt[
        ConjugateTranspose[stateDifference].stateDifference]]);
   Return[trd];
   ];


derTraceDistance[excite_,densityState1_, densityState2_, rValue_, tauValue_] :=
   D[traceDistance[excite,densityState1, densityState2, rValue, tauValue], 
   tauValue];


nonMarkovMeasure[excite_, θ_, ϕ_, rValue_, tauValue_] := 
  Module[{},
   
   exciteNum = excite;
   state1 = {Cos[θ], Exp[I ϕ]*Sin[θ]};
   den1 = KroneckerProduct[state1, state1];
   state2 = {Sin[θ], -Exp[I ϕ]*Cos[θ]};
   den2 = KroneckerProduct[state2, state2];
   
   rate = Derivative[0,0,0,0,1][traceDistance][excite,den1, den2, rValue, tauValue];
   Return[rate]
   ];

maximiseNMM[excite_, rValue_, tauValue_] := Module[{},
   
   result = 
    Maximize[
     nonMarkovMeasure[excite, θ, ϕ, rValue, 
      tauValue], {θ, ϕ}];
   
   Return[result];
   ];

markovMeasure = Table[maximiseNMM[0, 0.05, t], {t, 1, 5}];

Select[markovMeasure, # > 0&]
```

Everytime I run this code, I get an error like the one below:

```
NMaximize::nnum: The function value -2.56488 (-0.00118823+(0.146982 +0.128055 I) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(1\)]\((\(\(0.14698239215186137`\)\( \)\) - 0.12805494426804936`\ I)\)\))-2.56488 (-0.00118823-(0.146982 +0.128055 I) (1/2 \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(1\)]\((\(-1.5526246457945858`\) - 0.3582826891743395`\ I)\)\)+1/2 \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(1\)]\((\(\(1.258659861490863`\)\( \)\) + 0.6143925777104382`\ I)\)\))) is not a number at {\[Theta],\[Phi]} = {0.918621,0.716689}.
```

In a nutshell, the code takes two input states. From there, the trace distance between those two states is then computed. After this is done, the derivative with respect to $\tau$ is taken. I am attempting to maximise this value with respect to the parameters $\theta$ and $\phi$, which are the parameters that define the states, for different values of $\tau$.

From the comments below, it seems the issue is that the derivative cannot be computed due to tau being give a specific value, as opposed to simply being left as an undefined variable. I am not really sure how mathematica uses the derivative. But essentially I need to calculate is with respect to $\tau$, then maximise w.r.t $\phi$ and $\theta$, then pass in a value for $\tau$.

I have now changed it from

```
derTraceDistance[excite,densityState1_, densityState2_, rValue_, tauValue_] :=
   D[traceDistance[excite,densityState1, densityState2, rValue, tauValue], 
   tauValue];
```

to

```
Derivative[0,0,0,0,1][traceDistance][excite,den1, den2, rValue, tauValue];
```

as I want to take the first derivative of traceDistance w.r.t it's fifth parameter, $\tau$ then I want to pass in the actual values for the variables.

Best I can tell, the reason may be due to

```
General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable.
```

which I think is happening as the derivative is being taken with respect to the value being passed in, 1, instead of the variable tauValue.

```
NMaximize::nnum: The function value -0.99123 (-0.0145768-(0.146982 +0.128055 I) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(1\)]\((\(-0.14698239215186137`\) + 0.12805494426804936`\ I)\)\)+(0.350778 +0.305607 I) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(1\)]\((\(\(0.35077827528107836`\)\( \)\) - 0.3056073032554202`\ I)\)\))-0.99123 (-0.0145768+(0.146982 +<<20>> I) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(<<1>>\)]\((<<1>>)\)\)+(0.350778 +0.305607 I) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(1\)]\((\(\(0.35077827528107836`\)\( \)\) - 0.3056073032554202`\ I)\)\)) is not a number at {\[Theta],\[Phi]} = {0.918621,0.716689}.
```

Which seems to be what the PartialD is stating in this error. However, I need to pass in a value for the variable, but I am unsure how I would force mathematica due take the derivative before the value is passed in.

Comment: You need to fix this: `General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable.`. You're using `Block[{}, ...]` and then setting variables up inside which will leak out. Try this: `Block[{}, xyz=3];Print[xyz]` and you'll see the problem. What you need is `Module` and all local variables must be in the list. Also you are maximizing over `tauValue`, but the `tauValue` is replaced by a number from the argument so it's not a variable anymore. Also you don't pattern test the arguments for `NumericQ` so that might affect evaluation order.

Comment: Apologies, I don't see what you mean about block. I have been setting up variables in block functions for over a year now and this has never been a problem before. For example, I can create a variable in block, evaluate the function and then access said variable with no issues.

Comment: Also, I am not maximizing over tau, I maximise over theta and phi.

Comment: Then you've been using it wrong. As I said, in this example: `Block[{}, xyz=3];Print[xyz]` the xyz retains its value after the `Block`. Another problem or perhaps more bad style: 
 in the function `stateEvolved` you refer to `exciteNum` but it hasn't been assigned a value either as a local variable or as an argument to the function. The main problem in your code is you are differentiating with respect to a number, not a variable. Finally `# > 0` is wrong in the `Select`, it should be `# > 0 &` you can also get rid of that `For` loop with `AppendTo` and just use `Table`.

Comment: I've rewritten your code to get past these issues, but something still goes wrong here `rho12 . spinRaise + rho21 . spinLower` because the rho are scalar complexes, but the spins are matrices. I'm afraid I know nothing about the domain of your problem to be able to fix this bit.

Comment: I started using block over module due to this blog post https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/ and a few comments on this stack exchange. Everyone says it provides a speedup, and using timing, I have seen this as well. Yeah I sorted the rho part, I mixed up the notation for matrix multiply and scalar mulitiplication.

Comment: The issue with exciteNum is maybe as you say, bad form. Not sure what you mean by number instead of variabled. I am unsure how to deal with the issue then. I need to differentiate in terms of tau. But I also need to evaluate the derivative over a range of values of tau as well. Would getting the derivative without assinging a value to tau and then evaluating the result using several values work better?

Comment: Well I might as well share what I did : https://pastebin.com/7Scfmzbq . There's that problem remaining with the dot products for you to fix. Test it with something like: `FullSimplify[nonMarkovMeasure[1, 0.9, 0.7, .4, .5]]` to see the dot product issue.

Comment: The advice in that blog about block vs module is correct although mostly a premature optimization, but you aren't using it like that. You're doing it like this: `Block[{}, x=3; ... more code ...]` but you should be doing `Block[{x = 3}, ... more code ...]` and putting the assignments in the list. It is better if these assignments are write-once too.

Comment: @GaussStrife Suppose I have debugged code. What should I get as output? Now I got `{}`.

Comment: Replace `Maximize` with `NMaximize`, `D` with `ND` (The syntax should be adjusted of course), and fix other simple mistakes,  one can get a `markovMeasure`: `{{-1.77066*10^-11 + 
   0. I, {θ -> -1.31462*10^-10, ϕ -> 1.5708}}, {-1.6629*10^-11 + 
   0. I, {θ -> 2.17712*10^-10, ϕ -> 1.5708}}, {-2.59719*10^-11 + 
   0. I, {θ -> -3.35892*10^-10, ϕ -> 1.5708}}, {-1.89377*10^-11 + 
   0. I, {θ -> 1.5708, ϕ -> 1.5708}}, {-3.18564*10^-11 + 
   0. I, {θ -> 1.5708, ϕ -> 1.5708}}}`. If this isn't the desired result, the code should be re-checked.

Comment: @xzczd I think you've mixed up $\theta$ and $\phi$. $\theta$ is maximised at $\pi/2$, not $\phi$. Just finished re-writing all the code. Issue wasn't with D or with Maximize. It was with D not knowing what to do with conjugate.